# Python--String error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Was given some code (I am using Python 3.2), and keep getting the below error.

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

grid = collections.Counter()

with open("test1.csv", "r") as fp:
reader = csv.reader(fp)
for line in reader:
    for pair in itertools.combinations(line, 2):
        grid[pair] += 1
        grid[pair[::-1]] += 1

actors = sorted(set(pair[0] for pair in grid))

with open("connection_grid.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow([''] + actors)
    for actor in actors:
        line = [actor,] + [grid[actor, other] for other in actors]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

But I am getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python32/test.py", line 21, in     writer.writerow([''] + actors) ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: You edited the second `with` to use `as csvfile`, but the `writer` is still attempting to refer to `fp`.  That won't work.

Comment: `writer = csv.writer(fp)` on this line replace fp with csvfile

Comment: Guys, those are answers, not comments.

Comment: That's okay, they must not want the status points :)

Comment: @yak: this is my code from another question (edited by the OP, and written for 2.7 while the OP ran it in 3.2).  Didn't want to double-dip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `b` is in the mode then the file is opened in binary mode, not text mode. Remove it.

Comment: That is very helpful! But, now I am getting the error: 'Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Python32/test.py", line 21, in <module> writer.writerow([''] + actors)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' I have updated the question with your fix and the new error.

Comment: Don't do that. Open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referring to the wrong variable. Early on, you create a file object `fp` and later you create `csvwriter`. In the second part, you should be writing to `csvwriter`, but instead you write to `fp`. The exception is telling you that `fp` is already closed, which is what happens when you dedent from the `with` block.

The first block is fine:

```
with open("test1.csv", "r") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    ...
```

Notice that the second block still refers to `fp`:

```
with open("connection_grid.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    ...
```

Comment: The code still won't work that way, though; the OP is using 3.2, and so `open` would need to be called with `newline=''`.

Comment: I'll leave this as is, given that the exception encountered is from working on the closed file.

Answer (score 0):

The doc for `csv` module says to `open(fname, 'rb')` or `'wb'` -- i.e. in binary mode. But this holds only for Python 2.x.

In Python 3, the CSV file must be open in normal, text mode. However, there still must be done something special. The doc says (see http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> If csvfile is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`.

So, the correct way is:

```
with open("test1.csv", newline='') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    ...
...
with open("connection_grid.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    ...
```

Ohterwise, Tim already pointed out that you passed by mistake the wrong file object to the writer. Exactly because of that, it is better to give variables realy descriptive names. It also helps when you give the file-object variables rather different names than file-names variables.

Also because of future modification of the code, it may be good idea to assign the file names to variables first. Then it is easy to convert the block of code to a function body later, like this:

```
def csv_transformation(csvname_in, csvname_out):
    with open(csvname_in, newline='') as finput:
        reader = csv.reader(finput)
        ...
    ...
    with open(csvname_out, 'w', newline='') as foutput:
        writer = csv.writer(foutput)
        ...
```

In such case, it is more difficult to make the mistake.